# Filtering Motion Data in Python by Maximum Position for each Time Period

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, curve-fitting, data-cleaning

I am trying to filter data points by time and position in python so that only the highest position for each second of time is left in the data set. So here is the situation, I used a motion sensor to record the oscillations of a spring/mass system and I am trying to do an exponential curve fit of the damping. The highest position decreases over time, and the periods last about a second. I thought maybe if I turned the times into integers then I could get rid of everything except the max position for each second. I do not know how to do this while keeping everything in order, so that when I am done, each position is still aligned with the correct time.

I tried using excel but it kept freezing and since the data I have includes every position, when I try to do a trendline it follows the average.

Comment: You probably want [pandas.Grouper](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html). The documentation should get you started. If you still have problems, edit the post to add what you´ve tried.

Answer (score 0):

Since you actually want just the peaks, you can try this:

Initializing some values for the demonstration. You will not need this.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

x = np.arange(0, 100)
y = np.sin(x/3)*np.exp(-x/20)

df = pd.DataFrame({"y": y}, index=x)
```

I want to compare each point to the previous and the next point, so I create three sequences:

```py
df_minus_1 = df.y[0:-2]
df_0       = df.y[1:-1]
df_plus_1  = df.y[2:]
```

Then I find which points are larger than the two neighbors:

```py
peaks = (df_minus_1.values < df_0.values) & (df_plus_1.values <= df_0.values)
```

And use this array to filter the original DataFrame:

```py
df_peak = df_0[peaks]
```

You can see the result here:

```py
pl.plot(x, y)
pl.plot(df_peak, "o")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I ended up using similar code to locate all the peaks and it worked great. I appreciate the help.